# Asp.Net MVC returnUlr hack

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have a Website written in Asp.Net MVC.

I have been getting strange requests to my website which I think is a Hacking attempt but I'm clueless at what is being tried.

The requests are like this, but vary in length.

```
/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FreturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FreturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FreturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FreturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FreturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FMembers%2525252525252FMemberInfo%2525252525252FDaddyPat

/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FreturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FreturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FreturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FreturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FreturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FMembers%2525252525252FMemberInfo%2525252525252FCumberdum

/Account/Login?returnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FreturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FreturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FreturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FreturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FreturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FreturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FMembers%2525252525252FOrgInfo%2525252525252FCGG
```

I'm not supporting normal login with name and password but only showing a button which allows you to login with steam using the openid.

When I open the link myself it just takes me to the login page and does nothing. Is the bot just stopping as I do not have a Name and Password input boxes?

Comment: Yes, there are many crawlers searching for easy security holes in the servers, we have some servers in Amazon and we have constant traffic (specially from Russia, China and India) with attempts to gain access to systems with default credentials (paths like phpadmin/, wordpres/logins and more) even one day some one let a Redis instance open in the wild, few hours later we receive a letter from Amazon warning us that our server was spamming all over the place, so be careful

Comment: Yes i'm getting those as well. But i'm getting flooded by requests like the ones mentioned. As far as I can tell its not doing anything. And I'm very curious wat its trying to do. Is it just a dumb bot which Will go away after a while? Should I respond with a 404, 401 or another code?

Comment: Maybe they think they can exploit some security breach, so, just a matter of time they leave you alone, however i would recommend to add IP restrictions if possible, and stop this requests as soon as possible, since the still cause the server to work, you can check CouldFare or something similar to avoid this kind of traffic